# Pantalla completa con iconos Awesome

Tags: javascript, html

Hola estoy haciendo una aplicación web y quiero agregar un botón de pantalla completa pero con icon awesome.

Estoy usando el siguiente código pero quiero que en vez de que se cambie el texto del botón se carguen **estos iconos**:

```html
<i class="fa-solid fa-expand"></i>
<i id= "btn_exit" class="fa-solid fa-down-left-and-up-right-to-center"></i>
```

**Este es el botón:**

```html
<button id="btn">Ir a Pantalla Completa</button>
```

**Y este es el codigo JS:**

```javascript
let myDocument = document.documentElement;
let btn=document.getElementById("btn"); 

btn.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    if (btn.textContent =="Ir a Pantalla Completa"){
        if(myDocument.requestFullscreen){
            myDocument.requestFullscreen();
        }
        else if(myDocument.msRequestfullscreen){
            myDocument.msRequestfullscreen();
        }
        else if(myDocument.mozRequestfullscreen){
            myDocument.mozRequestfullscreen();
        }
        else if(myDocument.webkitRequestFullscreen){
            myDocument.webkitRequestFullscreen();
        }
       btn.textContent= "Salir de Pantalla Completa";
    }
    else{
        if (document.exitFullscreen){
            document.exitFullscreen();
        }
        else if(document.msexitFulscreen){
            document.msRequestfulscreen();
        }
        else if(document.mozexitFullscreen){
            document.mozRequestfullscreen();
        }
        else if(document.webkitexitFullscreen){
            document.webkitexitFullscreen();
        }
        btn.textContent="Ir a Pantalla Completa";
    }
});
```

Agradezco su ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Una de muchas opciones sería dentro del button colocar el texto y el icono por separado con una  y un , cada uno con id. Y a estos les modificas la información:

```
<button id="btn">
   <i id= "btn_exit" class="fa-solid fa-expand"></i>
   <span id= "span_exit">Ir a Pantalla Completa</span>
</button>
```

Y el javascript:

```
let myDocument = document.documentElement;
let btn = document.getElementById("btn");
let span_exit = document.getElementById("span_exit"); 
let btn_exit = document.getElementById("btn_exit"); 

btn.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    if (span_exit.textContent =="Ir a Pantalla Completa"){
        if(myDocument.requestFullscreen){
            myDocument.requestFullscreen();
        }
        else if(myDocument.msRequestfullscreen){
            myDocument.msRequestfullscreen();
        }
        else if(myDocument.mozRequestfullscreen){
            myDocument.mozRequestfullscreen();
        }
        else if(myDocument.webkitRequestFullscreen){
            myDocument.webkitRequestFullscreen();
        }
        span_exit.textContent= "Salir de Pantalla Completa ";
        btn_exit.className = "fa-solid fa-down-left-and-up-right-to-center";
    }
    else{
        if (myDocument.exitFullscreen){
            myDocument.exitFullscreen();
        }
        else if(myDocument.msexitFulscreen){
            myDocument.msRequestfulscreen();
        }
        else if(myDocument.mozexitFullscreen){
            myDocument.mozRequestfullscreen();
        }
        else if(myDocument.webkitexitFullscreen){
            myDocument.webkitexitFullscreen();
        }
        span_exit.textContent = "  Ir a Pantalla Completa";
        btn_exit.className = "fa-solid fa-expand";
    }
});
```

De resto, ajustar las funciones JS para que funcionen bien.

Comment: Gracias @Marce Puente, la verdad no fui capaz de darle formato al código.

Comment: no tenes nada que agradecer, el sistema es bastante abstruzo, yo copio el código, lo idento el el IDE, lo pego acá y le doy a **{}** para que lo idente 4 espacios.

Answer (score 0):

Hola muchas gracias ya me funcionó el codigo utilizando className. El boton quedo asi:

```
<button id="btn" class="fa-solid fa-expand"></button>
```

y el Java script:

```html
let myDocument = document.documentElement;
let btn=document.getElementById("btn"); 


btn.addEventListener("click",()=>{
if (btn.className=="fa-solid fa-expand"){
    if(myDocument.requestFullscreen){
        myDocument.requestFullscreen();
    }
    else if(myDocument.msRequestfullscreen){
        myDocument.msRequestfullscreen();
    }
    else if(myDocument.mozRequestfullscreen){
    myDocument.mozRequestfullscreen();
}
else if(myDocument.webkitRequestFullscreen){
    myDocument.webkitRequestFullscreen();
}
   btn.className="fa-solid fa-compress";
   
}
else{
if (document.exitFullscreen){
    document.exitFullscreen();
}
else if(document.msexitFulscreen){
    document.msRequestfulscreen();
}
else if(document.mozexitFullscreen){
    document.mozRequestfullscreen();
}
else if(document.webkitexitFullscreen){
    document.webkitexitFullscreen();
}

    btn.className="fa-solid fa-expand";
}

} );
```